# Pandas DataFrame.to_csv() OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument and PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv, errno

I am writing a large number of financial time series datas to individual CSV files. In one instance I have found that the to_csv method repeatably fails but I cannot for the life of me figure out why. During the call to method to_csv everything just hangs for upwards of 10-15 minutes. Before crashing with the the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py",
>   line 172, in save
>       self._save()   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py",
>   line 274, in _save
>       self._save_header()   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py",
>   line 242, in _save_header
>       writer.writerow(encoded_labels) OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "securitiesArchives.py",
>   line 1072, in 
>       out_df.to_csv("PRN.csv",mode='w',encoding='UTF-8' ,compression=None)     File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",
>   line 3020, in to_csv
>       formatter.save()   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py",
>   line 187, in save
>       f.close() OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

It seems to be hanging up while writing the header row of the csv file. I wrote the same frame to hdf, then loaded from hdf, and using the hdf loaded frame, reproduced the same (or very close to the same) failure:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py",
>   line 172, in save
>       self._save()   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py",
>   line 274, in _save
>       self._save_header()   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py",
>   line 242, in _save_header
>       writer.writerow(encoded_labels) PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "bad_archive.py", line 12,
>   in 
>       #out_df.to_csv("PRN.csv",mode='w',encoding='UTF-8' ,compression=None)   File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",
>   line 3020, in to_csv
>       formatter.save()   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py",
>   line 187, in save
>       f.close() PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Not sure why it changed from "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument" to "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied" when moving from a larger code body to a small sample problem. I have searched for these errors in relation to the method to_csv and have seen that previous version of pandas may have had similar issues but this was supposed to be resolved in a later version. My pandas is:

> INSTALLED VERSIONS
>   ------------------ commit: None python: 3.7.3.final.0 python-bits: 64 OS: Windows OS-release: 10 machine: AMD64 processor: Intel64 Family 6
>   Model 94 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel byteorder: little LC_ALL: None LANG:
>   None LOCALE: None.None
>
> pandas: 0.24.2 pytest: 5.0.1 pip: 19.1.1 setuptools: 41.0.1 Cython:
>   0.29.12 numpy: 1.16.4 scipy: 1.2.1 pyarrow: None xarray: None IPython: 7.6.1 sphinx: 2.1.2 patsy: 0.5.1 dateutil: 2.8.0 pytz: 2019.1 blosc: None bottleneck: 1.2.1 tables: 3.5.2 numexpr: 2.6.9 feather: None
>   matplotlib: 3.1.0 openpyxl: 2.6.2 xlrd: 1.2.0 xlwt: 1.3.0 xlsxwriter:
>   1.1.8 lxml.etree: 4.3.4 bs4: 4.7.1 html5lib: 1.0.1 sqlalchemy: 1.3.5 pymysql: None psycopg2: None jinja2: 2.10.1 s3fs: None fastparquet:
>   None pandas_gbq: None pandas_datareader: 0.8.1 gcsfs: None

I am on a win-10 64 bit machine using Anaconda Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 15:29:51) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

I have tried:

- convert index to str to astype(str) prior to calling to_csv, same issue
- dropna on index (rows) as there were a large number of NaN entries (originally this frame was part of a much larger multi index frame) problem persists
- keyword arguments headers=False and index=False, neither changed the behavior.
- Using .loc[] to slice first row only and perform to_csv on this

`out_df.loc[out_df.index.values[0]].to_csv("PRN.csv",mode='w',encoding='UTF-8' ,compression=None)`

which also failed. Even though this is now a series and no longer a frame as the following warning was produced

> FutureWarning: The signature of `Series.to_csv` was aligned to that of
>   `DataFrame.to_csv`, and argument 'header' will change its default
>   value from False to True: please pass an explicit value to suppress this warning.

- Tried again same method as above instead slicing the first two row to ensure it remained a frame and not converted to series

[The entire two row DataFrame which refuses cooperation with to_csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6LaC.png)
    `out_df.loc[out_df.index.values[0]:out_df.index.values[1]].to_csv("PRN.csv",mode='w',encoding='UTF-8' ,compression=None,index=False,header=False)`

But this also failed as before. I was however, able to write the sequence of each column independently to its own CSV file without issue.

```
for col_name in out_df.columns:
   print('Writing '+col_name+' as CSV')
    out_df[col_name].to_csv(col_name.replace(' ','_')+"_PRN.csv",mode='w',encoding='UTF-8' ,compression=None)
    print('Done.')
```

Combined, the above success, and failure of the two row write attempt, makes me think this is not an issue related to specific columns values. Further, the tracebacks make me think this issues is related to writing the column headers. But the thing is I have 3000+ other DataFrames withe the exact same column labels and they write to csv using to_csv without issue. At this point I am out of my depth.

Failure occurs on this same set of data repeatedly whether I am using the data I wrote to hdf or using a fresh pull from yahoo using yfinance. The following code reliably recreates the issue on my system:

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

good_df = yf.download(tickers='AAPL',interval='1m',period='7d')
bad_df = yf.download(tickers='PRN',interval='1m',period='7d')
print('Writing test case AAPL as CSV')   
good_df.to_csv("AAPL.csv",mode='w',encoding='UTF-8' ,compression=None) 
print('Writing test case PRN as CSV')   
bad_df.to_csv("PRN.csv",mode='w',encoding='UTF-8' ,compression=None)
```

Anyone have any ideas?

PS - While re-reading I decided to check the column labels for equivalence and as far as a Boolean comparison is concerned those of the 'good' DataFrame and those of the 'bad' DataFrame as identical.

```
>>>print(good_df.columns)
Index(['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Adj Close', 'Volume'], dtype='object') 
>>>print(bad_df.columns)
Index(['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Adj Close','Volume'], dtype='object') 
>>>print(good_df.columns == bad_df.columns)
[ True  True  True  True  True  True]
```

PPS - I also have tried removing all flags from to_csv though they should have been the default values. It was a carry-over from as used in other code and I was going through different values to see if it would work. The most basic to_csv call fails as before

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

good_df = yf.download(tickers='AAPL',interval='1m',period='7d')
bad_df = yf.download(tickers='PRN',interval='1m',period='7d')
print('Writing test case AAPL as CSV')   
good_df.to_csv("AAPL.csv") 
print('Writing test case PRN as CSV')   
bad_df.to_csv("PRN.csv")
```

### Update In response to reply from Cheng

I can see no file in explorer or via dir in console. But to test this I used a new file name that was not the symbol "PRN" and lo'n'behold it works.

I did not think this was the issue as I already tried writing to a different destination folder, both in the larger parent code, and then in the toy problem. Neither worked.

It would seem that windows has an old reference to any old file named "PRN.csv" or something....how frustrating. Lets hope a simple restart fixes it.

Thanks!

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/613313/why-cant-we-make-con-prn-null-folder-in-windows
PRN is not ok to be a valid file name under Windows OS! How crazy is that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I literally had this same problem earlier today, but since I was working with much smaller data, the solution was easier to spot.

When a file is opened in another program, you cannot write or append to it. Check for places where you might have forgotten to `close()` or if it's open for viewing in Microsoft Excel.

Also generally it's better to use `open('file', 'a')` to write in case there's any previous data you stored there. If not, it will do the same as `open('file','w')` and create a new file.

Comment: I was very intentionally using 'w' to blow away any existing data, as I have a different method to read the existing data, request new data, and perform an append. There must be a persistent reference somewhere that was not released.

Comment: glad I could help :)